# How does jQuery's mechanism of event handlers work

Tags: javascript, frameworks, jquery, event-programming

I'm in the need of widen my perspective on the framework libraries, to be able to make well aware choices of if/which/when to add a framework to a website.

One thing that got my attention was event handlers, as they seems to be somewhat more complex structured.

For me, in the early days, an event handler were added inline with its element `<a onclick="DoSomething();">...</a>`

Later on they were removed from being inline and added globally `document/element.onlick = "DoSomethingOnClick` or `document/element.onlick = "function() {...}`

As of today, the frameworks add their own mechanism on top and I am trying to grasp what/how that actually means/is done.

By studying code parts it appears to me, and here describe in a VERY simple way, that they add the `onclick` event similar to above global and then pass the event when raised, into their own handler, which itself is an object structure containing stored/added functions and elements and their relationships.

Is this a correct observation? If not, then how is it done?

Can this be showed with a simple written sample in Javascript?

Based on the following quote,

> "You can use the jQuery *on* method to attach an event handler to the document, and pass it a filter string that will cause your handler only to fire when the event happens on an element that match the filter, and with the matched element as *this* value."

how is the element that triggered the event identified in the handler (by the event object or ?) and how are the elements to be fired stored/identified?

Do the other frameworks, other than jQuery, have a very much different structure of their implementation of event handlers?

Comment: You can browse the jQuery source at [jQuery Source Viewer](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.event.add).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has an internal queue of all the handlers it has attached for a particular event on a particular element. The first time you bind an event to that element it initializes the queue and uses `addEventListener` to bind the event to jQuery's generic event-handling function. When the event is triggered, the function uses `event.target` to determine which element it is, and then finds the queue of handlers associated with it and calls them in the order that they were added.

The `on` method of delegation is nested on top of this. It takes advantage of *event bubbling*: when an event occurs, it's triggered on the specific target element and also all its containing elements. You bind the handler to a container, and it saves the selector string in the queue entry. When it's processing that entry in the handler queue, it tests whether `event.target` (which is still the specific element that you clicked on) matches the selector, and then executes the handler function. This mechanism allows you to bind handlers for elements that have not yet been added to the DOM; it's particularly useful when you have a list of elements that is updated dynamically (e.g. adding rows to a table).

Comment: +1 Thank you, your answer confirmed how I understood it to be

Comment: @Barmar Just curious. Which property of event.target can be utilized to match the css selector?

Comment: @Peter Any properties or attributes that can be used in a jQuery selector. It performs a test similar to `$(event.target).is(selector)`

Comment: @Barmar what happens (internally) when the same event is attached to the same element, multiple times. E.g. $('#mybutton').click(codeXX); $('#mybutton').click(codeXX); Will it still run it twice (internally) or will it cache and run only once? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew I think it will run multiple times, but you can easily test by using an event handler that calls `alert()` or `console.log()`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It runs multiple times. And it appears there is no setting to make it run only once...have to juggle with code above.

Comment: @Andrew You can do `#("#mybutton").off("click", funcName)` before adding the handler, to make sure it's not added twice.

Comment: @Barmar what if my selector is used with plugin-function and event is inside that function? I am using this function: https://codepen.io/patrickkahl/pen/KFmAb ('scrollPosReaload'). How can I make it run only once

Comment: @Andrew The plugin can do `$(this).off(...).on(...)` to ensure that it only adds one handler.

Comment: @Barmar you mean inside the function, i could do "$(this).off('click').on('click' , function(e) { ..." ??

Comment: @Andrew It should use `.off('click', functionname).on('click', functionname)`. or it should use a namespaced event. You don't want to remove other click handlers that the user added independently from the plugin.

Comment: @Barmar and what if my event function is anonymous...as it is now...can't do that? Need to create separate function with name and pass name, twice..?

Comment: That's why I suggested using a namespaced event. If you have a real question about this, post a question to StackOverflow, the comment section is not for extended discussion like this.

Comment: But wich is the order of calling function from the stack/quee?

Comment: @Andrea_86 They're called in the order that they were added.